# Reading a gzipped file using apache beam, wrapped in TextIOWrapper results in "'CompressedFile' object has no attribute 'writable'"

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm working to implement a simple CSV reader in apache beam, following along with the test from the beam repo: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b85795adbd22d8b5cf9ebc684ce43e172a789587/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio_test.py#L128-L148

```py
def get_csv_reader(readable_file):
  import sys
  import csv
  import io
  if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    return csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(readable_file.open()))
  else:
    return csv.reader(readable_file.open())

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  content_pc = (p
                | beam.Create([CSV_FILE])
                | fileio.ReadMatches()
                | beam.FlatMap(get_csv_reader)
                | beam.Map(print))
```

This works correctly if CSV_FILE is not compressed and I get no errors. However, if I use a gzipped file as input, I get:

```py
<ipython-input-114-4830c3592163> in get_csv_reader(readable_file)
      6   import io
      7   if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
----> 8     return csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(readable_file.open()))
      9   else:
     10     return csv.reader(readable_file.open())

AttributeError: 'CompressedFile' object has no attribute 'writable' [while running 'FlatMap(get_csv_reader)']
```

I understand why this is happening (that TextIOWrapper is looking for a readable AND writable object). Are there folks with more insight into apache beam/dataflow who can suggest how best to implement this to handle both compressed and uncompressed inputs?

Comment: I tried your code snippet, yeah.  interesting question. Though I feel the root cause has nothing to do with beam?   Putting it under correct tag wouldl help finding the right answer sooner.

Comment: Thanks, @RuoyunHuang. Why do you think the root cause is not related to beam (I'm truly curious)? The `AttributeError` is with `CompressedFile`. Interestingly, it looks to me like the `ReadableFile` object (from which `CompressedFile` inherits, I think) has a `writeable` attribute, but not a `writable` attribute (note the spelling difference). The code above works fine with a gzip.open() instead of the beam ReadableFile object open.

Comment: Ah. I see. You are right. I am new to python API didn't realize  ReadableFile is from beam.

Comment: This is not ideal, but the `ReadableFile` contains the file path as an attribute called `metadata.path`. You could use that to open the file: `filesystems.Filesystems.open(rf.metadata.path, compression=MY_COMPRESSION)`. You may still need to use a TextIOWrapper. LMK if that helps....

Comment: Thanks, @Pablo. That may be a workaround. Unless I hear otherwise, I think I am inclined to think that this behavior is at least unintentional if not a bug. Looks like JIRA is in my near future.

Comment: No worries. I've just written a fix: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/9861 - It should be available in Beam 2.18.0

Comment: Added the tip as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the 2.18.0 release in Beam, you will be able to do the following:

```
def get_csv_reader(readable_file):
  import sys
  import csv
  import io
  if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    return csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(readable_file.open(compression_type=MY_COMPRESSION)))
  else:
    return csv.reader(readable_file.open(compression_type=MY_COMPRESSION))

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  content_pc = (p
                | beam.Create([CSV_FILE])
                | fileio.ReadMatches()
                | beam.FlatMap(get_csv_reader)
                | beam.Map(print))
```

Comment: This works great for me in my initial testing.
Although now there are warnings as because the file is opened in a function which returns the reader I can't work out how to close it properly at the right time.
`ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='...'>`
Is this something to be ignored for now?

Answer (score 2):

The answer posted by Pablo ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529353/3828305 ) does not work even after I updated the Beam version to 2.18.0 or 2.19.0.

#### Reproduce to fail.

```py
GZ_FILE_PATTERN='/local/path/to/some-wildcard-*.gz'

def get_csv_reader(readable_file):
    return csv.reader(io.TextIOWrapper(readable_file.open(compression_type=CompressionTypes.GZIP)))


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    process = \
        (p
         | MatchFiles(GZ_FILE_PATTERN)
         | ReadMatches()
         | beam.FlatMap(get_csv_reader)
         | beam.Map(print)
         )
```

Error message:

> AttributeError: 'CompressedFile' object has no attribute 'writable' [while running 'FlatMap(get_csv_reader)']

(Not yet merged the patch and not fixed the issue as of v2.19.0?)

Currently I decided to avoid to use `CompressionTypes.GZIP` and decompress files by myself.

#### Reproduce to work correctly.

```py
GZ_FILE_PATTERN='/local/path/to/some-wildcard-*.gz'

def get_csv_reader(readable_file_metadata):
    # Hack: Pass UNCOMPRESSED to BEAM
    with FileSystems.open(readable_file_metadata.path, compression_type=CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED) as fopen:
        # decompress by myself
        decompressed_str = io.StringIO(gzip.decompress(fopen.read()).decode('utf-8'))
        return csv.reader(decompressed_str)


with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    process = \
        (p
         | MatchFiles(GZ_FILE_PATTERN)
         | beam.FlatMap(get_csv_reader)
         | beam.Map(print)
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [gecko655](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60812278/8277722), the accepted answer can result in an error. We can avoid the suggested workaround by decompressing the file ourselves.

```
def csv_reader(fn: str) -> List[str]:
    fp = GcsIO().open(fn)
    for r in gzip.open(fp):
        s = r.decode('utf-8')
        yield s.strip('\n').split(',')


def parse_csv(fn: str):
    csv = csv_reader(fn)
    # todo: manipulate csv and return iterable


result = (p | beam.Create([known_args.input]) | beam.FlatMap(parse_csv))
```